# Is there a way to install android application from eclipse to direct emulator sd card?

Tags: android, adb, android-install-apk

Hello To Every One Here

Here my problem is My Android application .apk size is 15MB and in My Emulator Some time it give insufficient Storage when i again install same application in same emulator due to less memory so i want to do one thing that is when i run build application it should install in to android emulator SD card which have at least 1Gb space .

How i can do to solve this?
My Emulator Android Version is 2.1 updated.
i also try this commands to set permission to install application into SD card.

```
adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2
```

but  this command give following Error:

```
Error: unknown command 'setInstallLocation'
```

is there any command that set permission to use External Memory Like SD Card to store new application install by Eclipse ADT.

Answer (score 2):

try uninstalling some of the applications in sdcard (if any). try restarting the emulator.

i guess installing in sdcard ***android:installLocation*** is from **FROYO (Android 2.2)** , so you can try creating an emulator for froyo and try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `adb install -s yourapp.apk`? `-s` means install on SD card. Alternatively you can run AVD with store size parameter – `emulator MyAVD  -partition-size 256`.

Comment: i known this will work well but i don't want to do all time to use this commands because when i change some thing in my application than again i have to run application than run this command to install .Is there any other way ?

Comment: I've updated my answer - run emulator with extended partition size.

Comment: @Herry- if you create a new emulator for android 2.2 and have **android:installLocation** in you manifest your issue may be solved. check my response.